# vuejs2 : reset variable when a event happened

Tags: variables, vuejs2, reset

I need reset a variable when a event happened in vuejs2

Here I have my code with 2 functions: "add" and "reset":
https://jsfiddle.net/uo19p71m/

```
var ggroupc = [
    {id: 1, country: "Francia", pj: 0, pg: 0, pe: 0, pp: 0, gf: 0, gc: 0, dg: 0, pt: 0},
    {id: 2, country: "Australia", pj: 0, pg: 0, pe: 0, pp: 0, gf: 0, gc: 0, dg: 0, pt: 0},
    {id: 3, country: "Peru", pj: 0, pg: 0, pe: 0, pp: 0, gf: 0, gc: 0, dg: 0, pt: 0},
    {id: 4, country: "Dinamarca", pj: 0, pg: 0, pe: 0, pp: 0, gf: 0, gc: 0, dg: 0, pt: 0}
];

var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        challenges: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4], [2, 3]],
        groupc: ggroupc
    },
    methods: {
        add: function () {
            this.groupc[0].pj++;
            this.groupc[1].pg++;
            this.challenges[0][0]++;
        },
        reset: function () {
            this.groupc = ggroupc;
        }
    }
});
```

I want to reset the "groupc" variable but doesn't "challenges" variable.

Some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the variable is a link to a place in memory

you must clear the counters

see corrected fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/simati/h6dt3t6n/

*also I added create new object with `Object.assign()` maybe you need it

in example:

1. open conosle (**chrome:** ctr + shift + i)
2. click button **log** see result
3. click button **add** and next click button **log** see result
4. click button **reset** and next click button **log** see result

**UPDATE:**

method `Object.assign()` not working, has been changed to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`

also method `resetIndex()` redesigned to reset on original counters

Comment: Hi. resetIndex function change the value to zero. I want to change to original value, maybe zero u other number.

Comment: ok. I redesigned answer. note: `Object.assign()` is not working, but I added other way to deep clone a object. see https://jsfiddle.net/simati/h6dt3t6n/

Comment: Yes! JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ggroupc)) works ! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not assigned by value in JavaScript, but by reference. This is important. Take the following example:

```
var array_original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array_copy = array_original;

array_copy[0] = 'd';
```

What you're doing seems to assume that `array_original` will still contain `['a', 'b', 'c']`, but it will actually contain `['d', 'b', 'c']` just like `array_copy` does!

If you want to fix your code, you're going to need to explicitly clone the array. Additionally, you'll need to be sure to make it a deep clone or you'll still have problems with the objects inside for the same reason!

Example of a deep clone using jQuery:

```
var array_original = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var array_copy = $.extend(true, [], array_original);
```

If you don't want to use jQuery, do some additional research into deep cloning of arrays of objects. Alternatively, don't define your `ggroupc` globally--instead, assign these values locally and use the `mounted` lifecycle hook!

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    challenges: [[1,2],[3,4],[1,3],[2,4],[1,4],[2,3]],
    groupc : ggroupc
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.reset();
  },
  methods: {
    add : function() {
      this.groupc[0].pj++;
      this.groupc[1].pg++;
      this.challenges[0][0]++;
    },
    reset : function() {
      this.groupc = [
        {id:1, country:"Francia", pj:0, pg:0, pe:0, pp:0, gf:0, gc:0, dg:0, pt:0},
        {id:2, country:"Australia", pj:0, pg:0, pe:0, pp:0, gf:0, gc:0, dg:0, pt:0},
        {id:3, country:"Peru", pj:0, pg:0, pe:0, pp:0, gf:0, gc:0, dg:0, pt:0},
        {id:4, country:"Dinamarca", pj:0, pg:0, pe:0, pp:0, gf:0, gc:0, dg:0, pt:0}
      ];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi I want to change to original value, maybe zero u other number.

Comment: Ok I understood about the copy in arrays but I don't know why I not must declare it as global variable. I tried use "Vue.util.extend({}, ggroupc)" but without positive results : (https://jsfiddle.net/uo19p71m/2/)

Comment: I just mentioned that arrays are referenced. Referencing means that instead of generating a copy of the array, the same exact array is shared between variables. So, changes in one variable will cause changes in every other variable. If you want to fix the problem, you must create an explicit clone of the array. Also, there are two problems with your fiddle: 1) you're using `ggroupc` as the initial value for `groupc` so the basic data is being modified, and 2) `Vue.util.extend` only does a shallow copy, not a deep copy.